# Training the named entity recognizer in SpaCy

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am trying to add a new entity to the SpaCy model for which I am followed this resource:
[Training the Entity Recognizer](https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/training/train_new_entity_type.py)

As per the documentation SpaCy requires a few 100 examples in order to add a new entity, which I have added accordingly.
Yet my model fails to recognize the new entity when presented by a random text.
What is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hello StarLord , I am facing same issue but the difference is i have successfully added new entity to spacy 'en' model and i saved it.Then i loaded this saved model and again added some more entities to it and then it just detecting newly added entities and forgetting the previous ones.if you find solution please let me know.

Comment: Hi @ParvezKhan. How did you add new entities to SpaCy model, I have provided over 300 examples for a custom entity, yet it is failing to register or recognize it.

Comment: I have followed guidelines mention here , https://spacy.io/docs/usage/training-ner

Comment: @ParvezKhan Hi, I followed the same resource, however it fails to understand my entitites, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: @StarLord Can you provide the code you're using to train the model?